Getting a User inputted vector
I have been trying to get my code to allow a user to insert a vector, but I keep getting the error message "Series object is not callable".
I am very new to python and am not sure what is wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated.
what I have now:
x_coor=input('Enter Vector:') 
vector_x = np.array(list(map(int, x_coor("Enter Vector:").split( ))))
print (vector_x)

enter image description here
look to get back a vector array [1, 2, 3, 4]
